# How to optimize these conditions IF

Tags: c#

I have a DataGridView that receives and displays IDs from an external source. I know the nicknames of each ID.

In the "ID" column, how would you optimize to see which nickname corresponds to the cell ID 0

Here is an example of what I did (see below) which works well but the IF conditions are too long because there are nearly 200 IDs with their nicknames.

Do you know a more optimized way like a loop that checks a list that contains all the nicknames of the members ? I hope you understood what I mean ;)

```
 string id = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
 var nom = "";

 if (id == "FB23E1A8B7E2944FAAEC6219BBDF8243")
 {
    nom = "Pseudo 1";
 }
 else if (id == "FE63D6040E22611D978B73064B3A2057")
 {
   nom = "Pseudo 2";
 }
 else if (id == "0D44A8E3F29D9E568FE31C7DE45A80E0")
 {
   nom = "Pseudo 3";
 }
```

Thanks

Comment: Use a dictionary to map ids to names?

Comment: Please read the description of a tag before using it. The VS tag specifically states that it for issues with the IDE, not for code that just happens to be written using VS. Your question would be the same if you wrote your code in Notepad, so the VS tag is not relevant.

Comment: since you said 200 IDs have you considered storing those IDs in a file (eg. csv) or database (eg. sqlite) instead of hardcoding them?

Comment: Thanks, yes I thought of storing them in a file.. I looked for how to do it but I couldn't find it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [`Dictionary<string, string>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=net-7.0):

```
var idNickNameMapping = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {"FB23E1A8B7E2944FAAEC6219BBDF8243", "Pseudo 1"}, {"FE63D6040E22611D978B73064B3A2057", "Pseudo 2"}, {"0D44A8E3F29D9E568FE31C7DE45A80E0", "Pseudo 3"}
};

string nom = idNickNameMapping.TryGetValue(id, out string name) ? name : null;
```

If the dictionary never changes make it a field in the class, for example:

```
private static readonly Dictionary<string, string> IdNickNameMapping = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {"FB23E1A8B7E2944FAAEC6219BBDF8243", "Pseudo 1"}, {"FE63D6040E22611D978B73064B3A2057", "Pseudo 2"}, {"0D44A8E3F29D9E568FE31C7DE45A80E0", "Pseudo 3"}
};
```

If you have 200 entries, like you've said, it might be better to store them in a file or database as Rand said in a comment. You can load them into the dictionary on application start. The collection initializer i have shown is just one way to fill a dictonary, you can also use a simple loop where you use the [`Add` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.add?view=net-7.0). If you use a `static` field the best place is the [static constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-constructors) of the class.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try, do you know if it's possible to store (ID and nicknames) in a file to use it in the dictionary?

Comment: @zollen123: of course it is possible. I mentioned it in my answer. But if you don't know how to read them from file, that's out of scope of this question. Read a tutorial or find another question on SO which shows it (or ask another). You're welcome